# linux tr command - splitting mysqldump inserts into different rows

Tags: linux, mysql, tr

I've got a mysqldump which have multiple rows put into one line:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_access` VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,1),(1,2,1,1,1,1),(1,3,1,1,1,1),(1,4,1,1,1,1),(1,5,1,1,1,1),(1,6,1,1,1,1),(1,7,1,1,1,1),(1,8,1,1,1,1),(1,9,1,1,1,1),(1,10,1,1,1,1),(1,11,1,1,1,1),(1,12,1,1,1,1),(1,13,1,1,1,1),(1,14,1,1,1,1),(1,15,1,1,1,1),(1,16,1,1,1,1),(1,17,1,1,1,1),(1,18,1,1,1,1),(1,20,1,1,1,1),(1,21,1,1,1,1),(1,22,1,1,1,1),(1,23,1,1,1,1),(1,24,1,1,1,1),(1,26,1,1,1,1),(1,27,1,1,1,1),(1,28,1,1,1,1),(1,29,1,1,1,1),(1,30,1,1,1,1),(1,31,1,1,1,1),(1,32,1,1,1,1),(1,33,1,1,1,1),(1,34,1,1,1,1),(1,35,1,1,1,1),(1,36,1,1,1,1),(1,37,1,1,1,1),(1,38,1,1,1,1),(1,39,1,1,1,1),(1,40,1,1,1,1),(1,41,1,1,1,1),(1,42,1,1,1,1),(1,43,1,1,1,1),(1,44,1,1,1,1),(1,47,1,1,1,1),(1,48,1,1,1,1),(1,49,1,1,1,1),(1,51,1,1,1,1),(1,52,1,1,1,1),(1,53,1,1,1,1),(1,54,1,1,1,1),(1,55,1,1,1,1),(1,56,1,1,1,1),(1,57,1,1,1,1),(1,58,1,1,1,1),(1,60,1,1,1,1),(1,61,1,1,1,1),(1,62,1,1,1,1),(1,63,1,1,1,1),(1,64,1,1,1,1),(1,65,1,1,1,1),(1,66,1,1,1,1),(1,67,1,1,1,1),(1,68,1,1,1,1);
```

I'd like to use the `tr` command to split them into distinct lines and I try to do:

```
cat dump.sql | tr ")," "),\n" | less
```

but it doesn't work (the output doesn't change, it's the same as the input file). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr` only does 1-to-1 replacement. Try `sed`:

```
cat dump.sql | sed -e 's/),/&\n/g' | less
```

Comment: marvelous! Nothing more than I really needed!

Comment: `cat` is probably unnecessary `sed -e 's/),/&\n/g' < dump.sql | less` should work just as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to archive what you want:

```
 sed -i.bak 's/),/),\n/g' dump.sql
```

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz this command does the replace in the same file and creates a backup file with .bak extension